# How can I add a space in between two outputs?

Tags: java

This is the code I am working with.

```
public void displayCustomerInfo() {
    System.out.println(Name + Income);
}
```

I use a separate main method with this code to call the method above:

```
first.displayCustomerInfo();
second.displayCustomerInfo();
third.displayCustomerInfo();
```

Is there a way to easily add spaces between the outputs? This is what it currently looks like:

```
Jaden100000.0
Angela70000.0
Bob10000.0
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a literal space, or a tab:

```
public void displayCustomerInfo() {
    System.out.println(Name + " " + Income);

    // or a tab
    System.out.println(Name + "\t" + Income);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use `System.out.printf()` like this if you want to get nicely formatted

```
System.out.printf("%-20s %s\n", Name, Income);
```

Prints like:

```
Jaden             100000.0
Angela            70000.0
Bob               10000.0
```

This format means:

```
%-20s  -> this is the first argument, Name, left justified and padded to 20 spaces.
%s     -> this is the second argument, Income, if income is a decimal swap with %f
\n     -> new line character
```

You could also add formatting to the Income argument so that the number is printed as desired

Check out this for a [quick reference](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Summer16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf)

Comment: any things for android?? how to do the same thing in android ?

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(Name + " " + Income);
```

Is that what you mean? That will put a space between the name and the income?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
 System.out.println(Name + " " + Income);
```

Answer (score 0):

+"\n" + can be added in print command to display the code block after it in next line

E.g. System.out.println ("a" + "\n" + "b") outputs a in first line and b in second line.

Answer (score 0):

**code:**

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        int a=10, b=20;
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
    }
}
```

**Input**: none

**Output**: 10 20

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class class2 {

    public void Multipleclass(){
       String x,y;
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter your First name");
       x=sc.next();
       System.out.println("Enter your Last name");
       y=sc.next();

       System.out.println(x+  " "  +y );
   }
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Yes sure System.out.println(x+ " " +y );