# Java Format A entire Line

Tags: java

Hello I tried using the java:

System.out.printf method but it is not working.

I am trying to create a menu like this: Age 4 spaces   Location 4 spaces   Price

I tried doing something like this System.out.printf("%4s Age Location Price");

I would like to format everything on one line!

This is what I want:

Age  (Four spaces between)     Location  (Another 4 spaces inbetween)       Price

Comment: Try to use a code block to make the question more readable.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to better explain what you want? You could just make a constant string with four space between your titles like "Age    Location    Price".

Comment: `System.out.printf("%-6s %-15s %-12s", "Age", "Location", "Price");`. You figure out the spacing :)

Comment: Put four spaces in the string?

Comment: @DevilsHnd thank you so much. If I do not want the age formatted, would I just do this? System.out.printf("%s %-15s %-12s", "Age", "Location", "Price"); I want to keep word where is is and only move the other two strings

Comment: `System.out.print("Age    Location    Price")` --- That's what you asked for, the 3 words, with 4 spaces between them. Or if you prefer: `System.out.printf("%s    %s    %s", "Age", "Location", "Price")`

Comment: Read up on the [printf()](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-printf-function-in-java) or [String#format()](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/10/java-string-format-method/) methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19393410/11624647

Answer (score 1):

> example
> `System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s", "Age", "Location", "Price");`
> This should print spaces between each word you want to print. Just replace my example with the amount of spaces you want.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what I want:
>
> Age (Four spaces between) Location (Another 4 spaces inbetween) Price

Well keep it simple then.  Just use `print` or `println`:

```
System.out.println("Age    Location    Price");
```

That's it.  Put required spaces into the string at the appropriate point and print it *without any further formatting*.  (Using `println` gives you want a newline following the text, which is probably what you need here.)

Now, you could use `PrintWriter.printf`, `PrintWriter.format` or `String.format` in this.  You might do that if you want to express the spacing in terms of column widths.  You might do it if the headings were variable sized.  Or other reasons.  But for *this* problem ... *as you have described it to us* ... formatting adds little value.

If you want (or need) to use to use `printf` etcetera then I *strongly recommend* that you read the method javadocs AND the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for the `Formatter` class.  The latter describes how this kind of Java formatting works.  By reading it carefully you can understand what it is capable of, and what its limitations are.